# Hide a RadComboBox drop down

Tags: jquery, telerik, radcombobox

I have a button in a footer section of drop down list.I want when i click on button the only drop down list to be hide along with the button.
I want to hide the only ItemTemplate content

This is sample code

```
             <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadCmbGeneralGroupCodes" runat="server"
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProcedureGroupCodes" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProcedureCode") + " "  + Eval("ProcedureName") %>'
               ToolTip='<%# Eval("ProcedureName") %>' ProcedureId='<%# Eval("ProcedureID") %>'
               ProcedureCode='<%# Eval("ProcedureCode") %>' 
               MaxQty='<%# Eval("MaxQty") %>'
               NoOfVisit='<%# Eval("NoOfVisit") %>'
               NoOfVisitForMainProc='<%# Eval("NoOfVisitForMainProc") %>'
               AddAdditionalPercentage='<%# Eval("AddAdditionalPercentage") %>'
               ParentProcedureID='<%# Eval("ParentProcedureID") %>'
               IsDenture='<%# Eval("IsDenture") %>'
               SurfaceCount='<%# Eval("SurfaceCount") %>'
               IsOptional='<%# Eval("IsOptional") %>'
               AlwaysOpt='<%# Eval("AlwaysOpt") %>'
               ToothEntry='<%# Eval("ToothEntry") %>'
               SurfaceType='<%# Eval("SurfaceType") %>'
               IsBillable='<%# Eval("IsBillable") %>
               AppliedToOffProv='<%# Eval("AppliedToOffProv") %>'
               DentalCost='<%# Eval("DentalCost") %>'
           OnClick="OnProcedureCodeItemChecked(this)"
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                <input id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I tried This but not working

```
$('#cancel').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('ItemTemplate').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you post you code.

Comment: Kishor i have added my code .Please just me the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the Dropdown of RadComboBox:   [Hide RadComboxBox](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/hide-drop-down-on-client.aspx)

```
$('#cancel').click(function () {
    var RadComboBox=$find("<%=RadCmbGeneralGroupCodes.ClientID%>")//find RadComboBox
    RadComboBox.hideDropDown();//hide RadComboBox dropdown
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, just use the `.hide()` function.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thGGv/)

**JavaScript**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('select').hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>I wish I was hidden</option>
</select>
<button>Hide us!</button>
```

If you had more than one button on the page you should assign an `id` to your `button`.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#hide-button').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('select').hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="hide-button">Hide us!</button>
```

Comment: you should use it with id. cause this will hide all the buttons and dropdown in current page

Comment: Am using telerik controls.

Comment: Hi @Somnath, that's not working because you need to first refer to cancel as `$('#cancel')` because you're referring to the ID. Then ItemTemplate isn't what is actually rendered to the page, you need to target the correct HTML element that it produces `$('input[type=checkbox]')` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mybutton").click(function(){

     //hide
     $(this).hide();
     $("select.myddlist").hide();

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`hide` is what you need here..

try this

```
$(function(){
    $("#yourButtonId").click(function(){
        $("#yourSelectid").hide();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```